# Create custom text transformation

Tags: macos, text-input

In a text box, I can right click and select Transformations > Make Uppercase.

Is it possible to create my own text transformations? a super simplified example would be to wrap the selected text in parenthesis.

Comment: did you try anything like Automator service, a Apple Script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an Automator service which accepts text and use the following AppleScript action:

[image]

```
on run {input}
    return "(" & (input as string) & ")"
end run
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also create `~/Library/Keybindings/` and save a property list like this as `~/Library/Keybindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
  // option-9 to wrap with parentheses
  "~9" = (setMark:, moveBackward:, insertText:, "(", swapWithMark:, moveForward:, moveForward:, insertText:, ")", moveBackward:);
}
```

Quit and reopen applications to apply the changes.

See http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html or https://github.com/ttscoff/KeyBindings/blob/master/DefaultKeyBinding.dict for more examples.